# Is there a more elegant way to colour ggplot bars with mean of data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, fill

There must be a less clunky way to summarise mean values in a bar chart. I expected fill to return a mean for all of the counts. See the MWE including the work around.

```
# Some data
Machine <- c( "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "G","H", "G")
Efficiency <- c(93.3, 95.0, 95.0, 99.1, 84.1, 95.8, 91.2, 82.9, 73.1, 93.7, 86.6, 68.1, 78.5, 68.5, 86.6, 90.0, 97.3)
gt <- data.frame(Machine, Efficiency)

ggplot(gt, aes(x=Machine, fill = Efficiency)) + geom_bar()
# This is not what I expected so...

library(dplyr)
gt2 <- gt %>% group_by(Machine) %>% mutate(mean(Efficiency))
names(gt2) <- c("Machine", "Efficiency", "Mean_Efficiency")

ggplot(gt2, aes(x=Machine, fill = Mean_Efficiency)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "count") 
# This is what I want (and mistakenly expected)
```

Is there a more elegant way to colour the bars according to the mean efficiency?

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what is your expected output ? Are you looking for an easier solution to get the second `ggplot` ? (using `gt2`)

Answer (score 3):

The reason that you first attempt does not give the expected result is that `ggplot2` cannot know that it is the mean of `Efficiency` that you want to use for filling. It could just as well be the sum or the median and `ggplot2` is right in not trying to guess something it cannot know.

So, the best solution is to precompute the mean. Your plot relies on two summaries, however: one is the mean that you precompute and the other is the counts which you let `ggplot2` (or, more specifically, `stat_count()` which is used by `geom_bar()`) do for you. If find this mix of methods for the summaries a bit confusing and would prefer to precompute both summaries as follows:

```
gt2 <- gt %>%
        group_by(Machine) %>%
        summarize(count = n(),
                  mean_efficiency = mean(Efficiency))
```

You can then use `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar()` since the former takes an explicit `y`-aesthetic in stead of plotting the counts:

```
ggplot(gt2, aes(x = Machine, y = count, fill = mean_efficiency)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Note that this solution is not more correct than yours. To me it is clearer than your solution, but of course this is also a matter of taste. It's up to you which you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

No pre-computation is needed if you call `ave` from within `aes`.

```
ggplot(gt, aes(x=Machine, fill = ave(Efficiency,Machine))) + geom_bar()
```

That is, directly set the `fill` aesthetic to be the mean of Efficiency over Machine.  For me this is a much more natural and readable approach, but as others have said it is a matter of taste.

If you want to set the legend title, use (eg) `+labs(fill="Mean efficiency")`

[image]

Comment: Fantastic George! I have not come across ave, relying on mean(). ```ave``` has the advantage of specifying the grouping variable. I had tried ```fill =  mean(Efficiency)``` but without specifying the grouping variable (which I assumed would be x) all I got was the average of all the Efficiency values. This is **Elegant**

Answer (score 0):

Your approach with computing the means before plotting was absolutely right. `fill`won't do that for you. However your code could be more concise without always setting names. (;

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Some data
gt <- data.frame(
  Machine = c( "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C","D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "G","H", "G"),
  Efficiency = c(93.3, 95.0, 95.0, 99.1, 84.1, 95.8, 91.2, 82.9, 73.1, 93.7, 86.6, 68.1, 78.5, 68.5, 86.6, 90.0, 97.3)
)
# aggregate(Efficiency~Machine, data=gt, FUN = mean)
gt <- gt %>% 
  group_by(Machine) %>% 
  mutate(Mean_Efficiency = mean(Efficiency)) %>% 
  ungroup() 

ggplot(gt, aes(x = Machine, fill = Mean_Efficiency)) + 
  geom_bar()
```